# "Comprehensive quality" vs "comprehensive qualities"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, word-request

To be exact, Which one is correct?

```
We should strengthen our comprehensive quality?
```

or

```
We should strengthen our comprehensive qualities?
```

Comment: Are you asking about overall quality, or about multiple distinct qualities?

Comment: @Davo Thanks. Maybe there are multiple distinct qualities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## It depends on what you want to say.

If you mean that you want to improve the quality of your comprehension, then "comprehensive quality" is correct.

If you mean that you have many qualities, and you want to strengthen them all, then "comprehensive qualities" is correct. (here comprehensive describes the qualities you will strengthen)